# customize uipopovercontroller in ipad

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

i want to change the image of popover. it is having blue tint at the top so i want it to be of different color. how can i do it...

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections  animated:(BOOL)animated
```

can i do it with this method.. make my own view and place a image in that view.

i read in some posts that it is not possible to change color and also i didnt fine any instance method of UIPopOverController class to do this..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Jaimin, Here the "view" - means the base view in which you want to show the popover. It doesn't mean that the popoverview which you are showing. You can't set the black border of the popover but here you can change the navigation bar color using - self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor. And you can set any image inside the popover using ImageView simply putting inside the view for whch you want to make the popoverview. Please let me know if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot customize a popover the way you want. The view you see is the popover's content. Popovers are always the way it is, black.

Comment: I want a black one but mine appears in blue everytime :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but it seems like it is possible to designate custom UIPopoverView backgrounds:
[UIPopoverBackgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html). Haven't got around to trying this myself.

> The UIPopoverBackgroundView class provides the background appearance for a popover. This class is abstract and must be subclassed before it can be used. The implementation of your subclass is responsible for providing the border decoration and arrow for the popover. Subclasses must also override all declared properties and methods to provide information about where to lay out the corresponding popover content and arrow.